# Write the derivative of the lower-triangular matrix $L(t)$ in terms of $L(t)$, $L^{-1}(t)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}A(t)$, where $A(t)=L(t)L^T(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Let $A(t)$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, thus by Cholesky decomposition, we have $A(t)=L(t)L^T(t)$ where $L(t)$ is lower triangular. Suppose $A(t)$ is differentiable.

> I want to write $\frac{d}{dt}L(t)$ as a function of $L(t)$, $L^{-1}(t)$ and $\frac{d}{dt}A(t)$.

I tried $$\frac{d}{dt}A(t)=\frac{d}{dt}L(t)L^T(t) + L(t)\frac{d}{dt}L^T(t).$$ I don't know how to proceed. I know that I need to separate $\frac{d}{dt}L(t)$ out. But it seems a troublesome task. Any hint please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compactness I'll write $C' := \frac{d}{dt} C(t)$ for any differentiable matrix-valued function.

**Hint** By the product rule you've found that
$$A' = L' L^{\top} + L (L')^{\top} .$$
Multiplying both sides on the left by $L^{-1}$ and on the right by $(L^{\top})^{-1}$ and canceling leaves
$$L^{-1} A' (L^{-1})^{\top} = L^{-1} L' + (L')^{\top} (L^{-1})^{\top} = L^{-1} L' + (L^{-1} L')^{\top} .$$

The key observations here are that (1) the first term on the r.h.s. is lower-triangular (it's a product of lower-triangular matrices) and (2) the two terms on the r.h.s. are transposes of one another.

**Additional hint** If $M$ is lower-triangular, then
\begin{align}M + M^{\top} &= \pmatrix{
m_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
m_{n1} & m_{n2} & \cdots & m_{nn}
} + \pmatrix{
m_{11} & m_{21} & \cdots & m_{n1} \\
0 & m_{22} & \cdots & m_{n2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & m_{nn}
} \\
&=
\pmatrix{
2 m_{11} & m_{21} & \cdots & m_{n1} \\
m_{21} & 2 m_{22} & \cdots & m_{n2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
m_{n1} & m_{n2} & \cdots & 2 m_{nn}
}
\end{align}
In particular, we can read off all of the entries of $M$ from the entries of $M + M^{\top}$.

Applying this procedure to $M = L^{-1} L'$ recovers $L^{-1} L'$ from $L^{-1} A' (L^{-1})^{\top}$.

Comment: I still don't get how to recover $M$ from $M+M^T$. Maybe I misunderstood something. Do you mean $M$ equals $M+M^T$ multiplied by something? Thank you!

Comment: I mean something less sophisticated than that: Reading off the entries of $M + M^{\top}$ tells you more or less immediately what the entries of $M$ are. I've modified the answer to make this more explicit.